# Google Maps tiles does appear when its run on iOS 9

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios9

I'm using Google maps tiles in iOS. The apps works fine on iOS 8. However, when I run the app on iOS 9. The Google maps itself appear, but the tiles doesn't.

it's quite strange. I didn't notice any errors. It just the tiles dosn't show up. Although on iOS 8 works fine.

Any clue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue with the solution on the following link:
 http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.